# get all the data treeview?

Tags: pyqt4, qtreeview

I need to get all the rows in an array.

As it is, this code returns all the data from the treeview and all the items in array from the treeview. I don't think I have the correct method; how can I fix this?

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()

        self.view = QtGui.QTreeView()

        #self.view.setEditTriggers(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.view.setModel(self.model)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)
        #parent = self.model.invisibleRootItem()
        self.model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Referencia","Nombre","Costo","UND","Precio"])

        for item in '1234 name 9999 10000'.split():
            self.model.appendRow([QtGui.QStandardItem(item),QtGui.QStandardItem(item),QtGui.QStandardItem(item),
                                  QtGui.QStandardItem(item),QtGui.QStandardItem(item),
                                  ])
        #self.view.setColumnWidth(0,50)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What do you mean by "get" all the rows, and from what array? I don't see anything returning anything.

Comment: Thank you. 
already fixed. 
apology but do not know much English.

Answer (score -1):

```
model = tableView.model()
data = []
for row in range(model.rowCount()):
    data.append([])
    for column in range(model.columnCount()):
        index = model.index(row, column)
        data[row].append(str(model.data(index).toString()))
```